# Python text file strings into columns in spreadsheet

Tags: python, export-to-excel

Huge newbie to python and this is probably really easy, but I can't get my head around it at all.

I have a text file with a number of rows following this format

```
 nothing doing    nothing[0]    doing[0] 
 hello world      hello[0]        world[2]
```

There are only spaces between the strings, no markers.

I'd like to extract these strings into excel file in the following format - so that each 'set' of strings are in a separate column.

```
           |        1      |       2        |       3
    ------------------------------------------------------
      1    | nothing doing |   nothing[0]   |  doing[0] 
    ------------------------------------------------------
      2    | hello world   |   hello[0]     |  world[2]
```

I've been looking at answers on here but they don't quite full fill this question.

Comment: Is the text file *exactly* like that? Are there tabs between like `nothing doing\tnothing[0]\tdoing[0]`? How do you differenciate between the first col with a space and the other two cols?

Comment: The text file is exactly like this. there are spaces between each set of strings.  No markers.

Comment: Your desired output file doesn't seem to have any commas (or any other fixed delimiter, like semicolons or tabs), but does seem to have vertical alignments.  IOW, it doesn't look much like a csv file.  Is that exactly the format you want?  If so, you can remove csv from the question, because neither the input nor the output are csv.

Comment: I just want them separated with commas or if opened in excel in separate columns

Comment: You can create excel spreadsheets using the python-excel package directly in python, I can post an answer on how I'd you'd like

Comment: @wnnmaw that'd be interesting, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, here's how you'd write to an actual Excel file. Note that my method of splitting isn't as complicated as others because this is mostly about writing to Excel.  You'll need the [python-excel](http://www.python-excel.org/) package to do this.

```
>>> data = []
>>> with open("data.txt") as f:
...     for line in f:
...         data.append([word for word in line.split("  ") if word])
...
>>> print data
[['nothing doing', 'nothing[0]', 'doing[0]\n'], ['hello world', 'hello[0]', 'world[2]']]
>>>
>>> import xlwt
>>> wb = xlwt.Workbook()
>>> sheet = wb.add_sheet("New Sheet")
>>> for row_index in range(len(data)):
...     for col_index in range(len(data[row_index])):
...         sheet.write(row_index, col_index, data[row_index][col_index])
>>>
>>> wb.save("newSheet.xls")
>>>
```

This produces a workbook with one sheet called "New Sheet" that looks like this

[image: Sample output]

Hopefully this helps

Comment: you mention the print data, there are over 600 rows to print!

Comment: Then don't print it! :P  I included that here so you can get a better idea of what I'm doing.  Its not necessary for this to work

Comment: removed the print because that was just stupid of me :P but again, this just produces all of the row in one excel cell :/

Comment: @user3220585 Did you make any changes aside from removing ```print```?

Comment: no changes at all, other than renaming the text file to my own

Comment: @user3220585, then it should work. You say its writing everything to the same cell?

Comment: yes. so in cell A1, I have "nothing doing nothing[0] doing[0]"

Comment: @user3220585, is the text file identical to as you posted? Are there at least two spaces between what should be columns?

Comment: identical. there are some that could have more spaces between them

Comment: More spaces won't cause problems, but anything with one space will be grouped together.  The only way for all of them to end up in the same cell is if they aren't split properly.  I should have asked this earlier, what version of Python are you on?

Comment: I'm on 2.7.6 32-bit, so it should be just fine.  I'm afraid I don't know what's wrong

Comment: OH. I sorted it. When I copied your code it had no spaces between the ""

Comment: @user3220585, yeah, that would do it, does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `numpy` to read the txt file and `csv` to write it as csv file. The `csv` package among others allows you to choose the delimiter of your preference.

```
import numpy
import csv

data = numpy.loadtxt('txtfile.txt', dtype=str)

with open('csvfile.csv', 'w') as fobj:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(fobj, delimiter=',')
    for row in data:
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: numpy library. I've never heard of this. I presume it needs to be downloaded?

Comment: it depends on the python distribution you use whether it is already installed or you need to install it. Python(x,y) includes `numpy` as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes that each "column" is separated by two or more space characters in a row and that they will never contain a comma in their content.

```
import csv
import re

splitting_pattern = re.compile(r" {2,}")  # two or more spaces in a row
input_filepath = 'text_file_strings.txt'
output_filepath = 'output.csv'

with open(input_filepath, 'rt') as inf, open(output_filepath, 'wb') as outf:
    writer = csv.writer(outf, dialect='excel')
    writer.writerow([''] + range(1, 4))  # header row
    for i, line in enumerate(inf, 1):
        line = splitting_pattern.sub(',', line.strip())
        writer.writerow([i] + line.split(','))
```

Contents of`output.csv`file created:

```
,1,2,3
1,nothing doing,nothing[0],doing[0]
2,hello world,hello[0],world[2]
```

Comment: this is currently exporting each row into one cell and not all the row is being displayed?

Comment: With the additional information you've added to your question, my updated answer should correct those problems.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes people who use mostly Excel get confused about the difference between how Excel displays its sheets and the csv representation in a file.  Here, even though @martineau gave you exactly what you showed you wanted, I think what you're actually going to want is something more like:

```
import re, csv

with open("infile.txt") as fp_in, open("outfile.csv", "wb") as fp_out:
    writer = csv.writer(fp_out)
    for line in fp_in:
        row = re.split("\s\s+", line.strip())
        writer.writerow(row)
```

which will turn

```
$ cat infile.txt 
nothing doing    nothing[0]    doing[0] 
hello world      hello[0]        world[2]
```

into

```
$ cat outfile.csv 
nothing doing,nothing[0],doing[0]
hello world,hello[0],world[2]
```

Comment: as long as there are guaranteed to be more than one space between columns

Comment: @BrianSchlenker: if that's not guaranteed, we'd have to come up with another rule to separate column from column, and that would require knowing more about the values themselves.