# convert txt file to xls in python and add new columns

Tags: python, excel, text, xls

I have a text file like this content :

```
28179
49172
40180
36228
29337
```

I want to convert text file to excel output **".xls"** that **has two columns** as follow :

```
ID    ----    Code
1     ----    28179
2     ----    49172
3     ----    40180
4     ----    36228
5     ----    29337
```

How can i do this with python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First import the [xlwt library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) and read the file and save it in an array:

```
import xlwt

data = []
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(line)
```

Then copy that array and write the new column to an Excel Spreadsheet:

```
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = wb.add_sheet("New Sheet")
for row_index in range(len(data)):
    for col_index in range(2)):
        if col_index == 1:
            sheet.write(row_index, col_index, row_index)
        if col_index == 2:
            sheet.write(row_index, col_index, data[row_index])

 wb.save("newSheet.xls")
```

This is a modified version of the code provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316568/python-text-file-strings-into-columns-in-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have the data saved in '**data.txt**' and if you could install,

```
pip install pyexcel-io
pip install pyexcel-xls
```

you can use the following code:

```
from pyexcel_io import save_data

SYMBOL = '----'

def data_gen(text_file):
    yield ['ID', SYMBOL, 'Code'] # first row
    with open(text_file, "r") as input_file:
        for row_index, element in enumerate(input_file, 1):
            yield row_index, SYMBOL, element.strip() # the rest

save_data("output.xls", {'data': data_gen("data.txt")})
```

if your data file exceeds 65,536 rows, you need to install

```
pip install pyexcel-xlsx
```

and update the last line of code as :

```
...
save_data("output.xlsx", {'data': data_gen("data.txt")})
```